# How can I fetch a large number of transactions?

Tags: rpc

Im trying to get a transaction through the api endpoint getTransaction.

The problem is i have a large basket of signatures(around 10.000) that i want for, each week.
Im currently working in python, so this take quite a while.

is there a more correct or faster way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `Connection` object has a `getTransactions(signatures: string[])` function that accepts an array of signatures  to fetch.

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTransactions